# Getting wrong timestamp of the incoming message in android

Tags: android, sms, timestamp

I am making an sms app in which i want to delete the sms on the basis of date and the originating address of the sms.`I already know how to delete the sms on the basis of these 2 criterias`.In the case of sms already present in the inbox,i am getting right timestamp of the sms using this code:

```
String date =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);    
String DateTime = MyDate.getDate(timestamp, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Log.d("Value: ","Value of date in ApplicationIntialiseCareTaker is "+DateTime);
```

But in the case of the new incoming sms, i am not getting the right timestamp of the sms and hence not able to delete the sms.This is the code i am using for getting timestamp of the sms in the case of incoming sms:

```
body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
long date = sms.getTimestampMillis();
```

Here with this code,the problem is that I am getting the timestamp with around 1 second delay as it supposed to be. e.g the actual time stamp is 12:10:32 but using this code in the case of receiving incoming sms, it is 12:10:33. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a rounding error to me. Do you care about milliseconds?

Comment: May be sir.This is the actual timestamp:  1352096923764  and this is the timestamp i am getting in the case of incoming sms :  1352096919000

Comment: Might want to evaluate a number of these things and see if it makes sense to only deal with digits significant to your use case.

Comment: Sir you can see that the last 3 digits of the timestamp i am getting are 0 which are not in the case of actual timestamp.Can you please tell me how to figure it out? I need the correct timestamp of the incoming sms so i would be able to delete it later by considering its timestamp.

Comment: It sound like the SMS time stamp is not going to give you the number of significant digits you get in regular time stamp, so you will need to match time stamps at 1 second resolution. Using whatever combination of division and floor rounding you might want to apply.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?i am not getting it completely.

Comment: If I gave you the number 1999 and 1000 and I wanted to check if they were equal to the next lowest 1000 (I.e don't round up), how would I go about doing that?  Probably something like (floor(1999/1000) == floor(1000/1000)) right?

Comment: You simply need to find out where your last significant digit is in the SMS time stamp, figure out how the rounding is being performed to produce your h:m:s format, and then figure out how to divide and round the system timestamp to match the SMS time stamp.